# Deciding which derived class is passed as an argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, argument-passing

I'm struggling with my current design and would like to know, if theres a possibility to decide which method to call without using a casting method. Say I've got a base `Fence` class.

And at the moment my workers know how to build wooden fences and how to build barb wire fences. And they can add two fences together... but up to now they only learned how to connect the wooden ones with wooden ones, and the barb wired ones with barb wired ones.

But as they probably will learn more, the Fence class has a virtual `addFence(const Fence& fence)` method.

As I wanted to avoid any casting methods, I tried to add special `addFence()`methods in both classes. Here is an example:

```cpp
class Fence {
public:
    virtual void addFence(const Fence& fence) = 0;
    ...
};

class BarbWireFence : public Fence {
public:
    ...
    void addFence(const Fence& fence) {
        //only add such a fence, if it is a barb wired one
    }
    void addFence(const BarbWireFence& fence) {
        //continue the fence with the given one
    }
};

class WoodenFence : public Fence {
public:
    ...
    void addFence(const Fence& fence) {
        //only add the fence, if it is a wooden one
    }
    void addFence(const WoodenFence& fence) {
        //continue the fence with the given one
    }
};
```

Now I would like to do something like

```cs
Fence *woodenFence1 = new WoodenFence();
Fence *woodenFence2 = new WoodenFence();
woodenFence1->addFence(*woodenFence2);
```

But as it is a runtime decision what sort of fence I've got, I only have the base `Fence*` pointer and therefore the definition of the base `class Fence` is used in the last line.

So is there a better implementation to decide 'automatically' what sort of fence I've got? Or should I use a completely different design?

Comment: In the general sense, if fences can't be generically connected as their base class, it seems like bad design to imply that they can. But that's just my opinion. Note that that is different from each class *implementing their own version of connecting a base fence to itself*, which is fine. Basically, you should focus on refactoring in a common *fence joining* API that operates on base fences, and then let each `fence` decide how to implement that API (likely through some form of the Template Pattern)

Comment: You can stay at base class level. Instead of adding a fenceA to a fenceB, have you considered connecting them? Connect both sides to each other: `baseFence.connect(otherBaseFence); otherFence.connect(baseFence)` and now each object (`WoddenFence`, `BarbedFence`) involved will be able to do what it has to do when being joined to something. In similar way, if the "board" or "play area" has to do something in this moment too, you can push the operation there `world.connectWalls(basefence1,basefence2)` and let it do what's needed, and it would notify/change things in those objects and itself.

Comment: If my suggestion above is not practical, and you really have cases where you need to keep the abstraction at the base Fence level, you could acomplish your goal via a form of dispatch; EX: Insert a field in the base class that represents the actual type of the Fence, then in each class's `addFence` method check this field and cast+call the appropriate method, or throw an `exception` if it doesn't know how to connect the other Fence. Dispatch gets very fragile when your inheritance tree gets more than a couple deep though.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl If I would like to use something like `world.connectWalls(fence1, fence2)` wouldn't I have the same problem again? As it is only decided at runtime, which sort of fence I have, wouldn't simply the `world.connectWalls(basefence, basefence)` be called?

Comment: Yes, you would have it back, I just mentioned it for completeness. My main suggestion was creating `connect` method that would be called **twice**, once for each side. In the `connectWalls` I mentioned, you would be able to call `baseFence.connect(otherBaseFence); otherFence.connect(baseFence)` **and** apply corrections/results to the `world` too. However, the most important thing is that the **two** invocations of connect would be dispatched virtually to the correct XYZFence class on each side, and each class could do exactly what it needs to complete its part of the operation.

Comment: However, that's purely design choice. Whether this or Visitor patter is more relevant, is up to you and up to specific details (like is it possible to separate the 'add' into 'two connects'? can 'connect' fail? if one connect failed, can the other be rolledback? how many really-different cases you really need to solve, maybe Visitor is too heavy for that? separation - do you even allow the WoodenFence to learn that BarbWireFence exist, maybe they are separe modules based on BaseFence? etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [binary methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=binary+method+object+oriented).

There is no satisfactory solution to this problem. You may want to learn about [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and its more formal sibling [the Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). These two things are basically the same, only presented a bit differently. In the most simplistic scenario you do this:

```
class WoodenFence;
class BarbWireFence;

class Fence {
public:
    virtual void addFence(const Fence& fence) = 0;
    virtual void addMe(BarbWireFence& fence) const = 0;
    virtual void addMe(WoodenFence& fence) const = 0;
    ...
};


class BarbWireFence : public Fence {
public:
    ...
    void addFence(const Fence& fence) {
      fence->addMe(*this);
    }
    void addMe(BarbWireFence& fence) const {
      fence->addBarbWireFence(*this);
    }
    void addMe(WoodenFence& fence) const {
      throw error("bad fence combo");
    }

    void addBarbWireFence(const BarbWireFence& fence) {
      // actually add fence...        
    }
};

class WoodenFence : public Fence {
public:
    ...
    void addFence(const Fence& fence) {
      fence->addMe(*this);
    }
    void addMe(BarbWireFence& fence) const {
      throw error("bad fence combo");
    }
    void addMe(WoodenFence& fence) const {
      fence->addWoodenFenceFence(*this);
    }

    void addWoodenFence(const WoodenFence& fence) {
      // actually add fence...        
    }

    ...
};
```

You can figure out what should happen when you add 10 other fence types.

There's a totally different direction one might take, namely, templatize the entire business and get rid of the Fence base class, as it doesn't provide a type-safe interface.

```
class BarbWireFence {
public:
...
void addSimilarFence(const BarbWireFence& fence) {
    //continue the fence with the given one
    }
};

class WoodenFence {
public:
...
void addSimilarFence(const WoodenFence& fence) {
    //continue the fence with the given one
    }
};

template <typename Fence>
void addFence (Fence& f1, const Fence& f2) {
   f1->addSimilarFence(f2);
}
```

Comment: I had totally forgot that ``*this`` would of course be of the correct compiletime type. You might want to add a comment about why you need separate ``addFence`` and ``addMe`` methods rather than just relying on ``addFence`` overloads (to stop infinite recursion on adding incompatible types that don't provide a specific overload of ``addFence`` declaring incompatibility)

Comment: The templated version wouldn't account for a situation where you have only base-class references, would it?

Comment: @aruisdante You don't have a base class in the templated version so you cannot have base-class references even if you want to. In a situation where you want to have a base class reference, you just templatize the entire entity (function or class) that is holding it.

Comment: doh, yeah, of course. But it looks like the OP is trying to deal with a situation where there would be, say, a `vector<Fence>` in some higher-level object that then tries to join them together. Templated method wouldn't help there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a general approach in C++ but assuming you have a fixed set of derived classes, you can actually deal with the situation using an extra indirection:

```
class BarbWireFence;
class WoodenFence;
class Fence {
public:
    virtual void add(Fence& fence) = 0;
    virtual void add(BarbWireFence& fence) = 0;
    virtual void add(WoodenFence& fence) = 0;
};

class BarbWireFence {
    void add(Fence& fence) override { fence.add(*this); }
    void add(BarbWireFence& fence) override; // deal with the actual addition
    void add(WoodenFence& fence) override;   // deal with the actual addition
};
class WoodenFence {
    void add(Fence& fence) override { fence.add(*this); }
    void add(BarbWireFence& fence) override; // deal with the actual addition
    void add(WoodenFence& fence) override;   // deal with the actual addition
};
```